# Using a singleton in C++

Tags: c++, singleton

I have a class which is a Singleton class. In the CPP file I have:

```
static std::unique_ptr<CStage> s;
    MSOCPPAPITYPE_(ICStage&) GetInstance()
    {
        try
        {
            s = std::make_unique<CStage>();
        }
        catch (...)
        {

        }
        return *s;
    }
```

Within another file I call `GetInstance().SetMValue(true);` which is a function that sets a member variable of the class to `true`. The default value of the member variable is `false`. Then I call `GetInstance().GetMValue();` which returns the value of the member variable. Instead of returning `true` I get a `false` return value. This causes me to believe that I am not properly using the singleton. How do I properly use my class as a singleton?

Comment: Looks like you unconditionally create a new instance of `CStage` here `s = std::make_unique<CStage>();` everytime `GetInstance()` is called.

Comment: I thought using a unique ptr would make it such that it wouldn't create a new instance of CStage?

Comment: No, that's what `static` is supposed to do in the singleton pattern. Please improve your question and make the example code self contained, especially the used macros. If it's not relevant, leave it out.

Comment: Don't make make dumb singletons, don't have problem implementing them.

Comment: @Puppy So how does one make smart singletons? ;)

Answer (score 2):

I can't see the need for using `std::unique_ptr` here. You can simplify your `GetInstance()` function as follows

```
static MSOCPPAPITYPE_(ICStage&) GetInstance() {
    static CStage theInstance;
    return theInstance;
}
```